# using spring eval tag and call the java method in jsp without scriptlet

Tags: java, spring, jsp, methods, eval

:-)

I have a one question. 
I want to checked status on my checkbox When myCode.id and checkedLists code value same.

```
<c:forEach var="myCode" items="${myCodeList }" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCode${status.index}" name="myCodes" />
    </th>
    <td>
      <textarea id="myContent${status.index}" name="myContents"></textarea>
    </td>
</th>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I toss myCodeList and checkedList from my Controller.
mycodeList is the list of the VO for some code list.
And checkedList is the list what I checked value from regist view.

```
<c:forEach var="myCode" items="${myCodeList }" varStatus="status">
  <c:set var="myCodeFlag" value="false"
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCode${status.index}" name="myCodes" 
        <c:forEach var="checkedCode" items="${checkedList}">
        <c:if test="${checkedCode.codId eq myCode.codId}">
        checked="checked"
        </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
      />
    </th>
    <td>
      <textarea id="myContent${status.index}" name="myContents"
<c:if test="${myCodeFlag eq flase}">disabeld="disabled"</c:if>>
      <c:forEach var="checkedCode" items="${checkedList}">
        <c:if test="${checkedCode.codId eq myCode.codId}">
        ${checkedCode.content}
        </c:if>
      </c:forEach>
</textarea>
    </td>
</th>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

It works like what I want.

But my boss told me that change the code more simple.
**Use the spring eval tag and call the java method**,
It means using Java Lists method contain in JSP.

So I tried like this in JSP page.
**`${checkedList.contains('${myCode.codId }') }`**

But it doesn't work.
What can I do to fix the problem?

Thank for your help.

Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the way to solve it.

**In Controller,**
**change the List of Object's to the Map of Objects.**

It means, I can write the code Like this.

**Before.**

```
<c:forEach var="myCode" items="${myCodeList }" varStatus="status">
  <c:set var="myCodeFlag" value="false"
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCode${status.index}" name="myCodes" 
        <c:forEach var="checkedCode" items="${checkedList}">
        <c:if test="${checkedCode.codId eq myCode.codId}">
        checked="checked"
        </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
      />
    </th>
    <td>
      <textarea id="myContent${status.index}" name="myContents"
<c:if test="${myCodeFlag eq flase}">disabeld="disabled"</c:if>>
      <c:forEach var="checkedCode" items="${checkedList}">
        <c:if test="${checkedCode.codId eq myCode.codId}">
        ${checkedCode.content}
        </c:if>
      </c:forEach>
</textarea>
    </td>
</th>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**After.**

```
    <textarea id="myContent${status.index}" name="myContents"
    <c:if test="${checkedCodeMap[checkCode.codValue].category.codId ne myCode.codId}">disabeld="disabled"</c:if>>
          <c:if test="${checkedCodeMap[checkCode.codValue].category.codId ne myCode.codId}">
${checkedCodeMap[checkCode.codValue].content}
          </c:if>
    </textarea>
```

It's better to read than before.